# VLC 3.0 not displaying subtitles, OSD

Tags: video, vlc

Does anyone know how to fix this bug? VLC 3.0.1 Git, stable, doesn't show any on screen display in full screen or window screen, nor the subtitles, even if they're loaded.

I've tried purging and reinstalling it, nothing seems to work. WHen I try to revert to an older version, e.g. 2.2.4, I cannot compile, i.e. configure the tar as I have dependecy inconsistencies. I don't care about the new version, I'd like to have OSD. Also, this kind of just stopped working, in one of the updates.

Using:

```
repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this was asked, but here's the solution that worked for me with VLC 3 from the same repository:

Tools > Preferences > Video > change the output field from Default to x11 video output (XCB).

Found it in a similar thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824067/vlc-does-not-show-any-text-at-all-not-only-subtitles).

Answer (score 1):

I simply did a reset.

Tools- Preferences- Subtitles/OSD- Reset Preferences- Restart VLC